# Know phrase or saying

Tags: gramática

If I want to say that I don't know a word, is it "No **sé** esta palabra" o "No **conozco** esta palabra".
Also, is it "No **sé** esta frase" or "No **conozco** esta frase"

Grammatically, I have researched the rules on **saber** and **conocer** but with these 2 words - palabra and frase - there seems to be contradictions when I checked on Chat Gpt. First, it said saber for "palabra" and then "conocer" for "frase " but later said depending on nuance both are acceptable.

I feel these sentences are used a lot so it would be nice to have a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. *Saber* refers to learning done, while *conocer* is more about experience having heard something before.

> Yo sé Francés y conozco la Torre Eiffel

---

You can say:

> No sé o no conozco esta palabra

This means that it is not in your vocabulary or that you have never heard it.

On the other hand, regarding a phrase you can say:

> No conozco esta frase

This means that you have never heard it, it is an idiom that you have never heard before.

Instead,

> No sé esta frase

It is not usual, it would only apply to a phrase that, as an example, is part of a learning text.

Comment: Thanks. So it is saber or conocer to know a word. Conocer is used for a phrase or idiom except if something needs to be learned off by heart then maybe saber can be used. I think this is what is meant

Comment: It is a somewhat subtle difference, only experience in speaking provides its proper use

Comment: Sometimes, as here, it is helpful to think of _conocer_ as _to be acquainted with_ in English. But the difference can indeed often be subtle.

Answer (score 2):

**Introducción**

El significado de *conocer* sería ‘haber experimentado una situación previamente’, mientras que *saber* significa ‘haber adquirido una determinada habilidad, facultad, capacidad y ser *capaz* de aplicarla a una determinada circunstancia’.

Pseudo-regla rápida para identificar:

- si el objeto sintáctico es un sustantivo puro suele pegar más **conocer**:

> Conozco Italia
> Conocés el mar Adriático
> Ojalá conociera el espacio
> (él/ella) Conoce el (des)amor
> Conozco la música electrónica

- si el objeto sintáctico es una cláusula o un verbo sustantivado suele pegar más **saber**:

> Sé lo que es pasar por tu situación
> Sé lo que se siente al estar en Italia
> Ojalá supiera lo que es estar en el espacio
> ¿Sabés cómo hacer esto?
> El sabe resolver cuentas
> Quiero saber/conocer cómo es la música electrónica

Algunas excepciones a mi pseudo-regla:

- Si lo que querés es hacer alarde de tus habilidades o capacidades, siempre se usa **saber (especialmente la construcción ‘me sé’)**:

> Me sé de memoria todas las aperturas de ajedrez

- Asimismo, si querés hacer alarde de tu experiencia, de haber pasado por una situación de la cual quién te escuche no la experimentó, suele usarse (en general) **conocer**

> Yo sí que conozco lo que es estar en el espacio (a diferencia de vos)

**Vamos a tu caso**

- Si es porque escuchaste (o leíste) una palabra que no la habías escuchado antes, entonces lo mejor es usar **conocer**.

> No **conozco** esa palabra (o bien: No conocía esa palabra)

- Si es porque no podés expresarte correctamente, e. d., hay una situación que no sos capaz de ponerla en palabras, lo mejor es **saber**.

> Y entonces (él/ella) quiso hacer ... ¡Ay, no **me sé** la palabra! (o bien: no **sé** cuál es la palabra)

En otras palabras, **conocer refiere al pasado** (porque *conozco* una experiencia que *ya tuve*, y sería rarísimo que alguien diga *conoceré*); mientras que **saber *suele referir* al presente o al futuro** (cuando me doy cuenta de que *sé* como aplicar mi conocimiento, no es otra cosa que aplicarlo a una situación posterior que a cuando me di cuenta). PERO, antes de haber preguntado, ¡no *conocías* la diferencia entre ambas palabras ni *sabías* cómo elegir correctamente el verbo apropiado! ¿Ya te está doliendo la cabeza?

**Posdata**

De todas formas, la frontera es difusa y pueden haber situaciones que no contemplé. En muchísimos casos ambos verbos son completamente aceptables e intercambiables. Probablemente tu duda haya surgido porque en el inglés se traducen como *know* ambos verbos. Algo de esto me hace acordar a cuando estudiaba la diferencia entre *make* y *do*. Si serán engañosas las palabras...

Comment: Gracias, Tac. Muy bien respuesta. Tengo que estudiarla aún más. Sí, tu comparación con los 2 verbos en inglés es igual. Como una angloparlante nativa los tengo por sentada pero sí son confusos.

Comment: "saber suele referir al presente o al futuro." Pero el chico no *supo* la respuesta a la pregunta en aquel momento.

Comment: @Lambie ¿Qué es lo que significa *suele referir* para vos? Es en general, no es una máxima absoluta. Yo mismo puse el contraejemplo, además que *refiera* a un tiempo no significa que el tiempo del verbo tiene que ser ése. En serio, a veces pienso que la gente de acá tiene serios problemas de comprensión de texto

Comment: ¿ Tengo o no el derecho de no estar de acuerdo? :)

Comment: @Lambie En verdad no entiendo cuál es el sentido de lo que me dijiste si yo mismo ya lo había mencionado en la respuesta

Comment: "En otras palabras, conocer refiere al pasado." Y voy a conocer tu abuela mañana.

Comment: @Lambie ‘A. Por lo tanto, A.’ Me alegro, una vez que la *hayas conocido* te vas a dar cuenta de que es la mejor abuela del mundo